# Pandas: merging two rows in dataframe by date but excluding others

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been playing around with the COVID-19 data available from Johns Hopkins. I've created a Python script to extract the data from Github, do some data cleanup, then load to a small SQL Server database I created. All of that works well.

Some of the data needs a little more massaging in order to accurately visualize it. There are missing FIPS numbers, missing lat/lons, etc. The issue I'm trying to resolve right now is to merge the confirmed counts which have null FIPS numbers with the FIPS number where everything else is the same. Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

In my searching, I found out about group by and sum:

```
df1.groupby(['STATE','COUNTRY','LAT','LON','DATE'],as_index=False).sum()
```

This will merge the two lines I want, but it also merges the FIPS where that lat/lon is 0 and sums the FIPS numbers (FIPS # 80049 and 90049).

How do I exclude all but the rows with null FIPS and the matching rows above them?

(I hope that makes sense.)

Thanks!

Edited to add data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
        [80049,'Utah','US',0.00000,0.00000,'2020-04-21',0], 
        [90049,'Utah','US',0.00000,0.00000,'2020-04-21',0], 
        [49017,'Utah','US',37.854472,-111.441876,'2020-04-21',0], 
        [None,'Utah','US',37.854472,-111.441876,'2020-04-21',70]
       ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1.columns=['FIPS', 'STATE', 'COUNTRY', 'LAT', 'LON', 'DATE', 'CONFIRMED']

df1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that null values are always preceded by their correct values. Using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on column `FIPS` will do so. You can see the usage `na_position="last"` although it's a default behavior, just to 
emphasize that nulls will be *preceded* by correct values if kept last.

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by="FIPS", na_position="last")
```

Now fill nulls with values in the previous record using method [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)

```
df1["FIPS"] = df1["FIPS"].bfill()
```

Finally you can use your groupby, adding `FIPS` to the keys:

```
df1.groupby(['FIPS', 'STATE','COUNTRY','LAT','LON','DATE']).sum()
```

Comment: Sorry it has taken so long to get back to this. The bfill() is filling from the bottom up instead of the top down. For instance, if the FIPS numbers are 40915, NaN, 40927, instead of returning 40915, 40915, 40927, it is returning 40915, 40927, 40927. I need it to fill from the top down.

Comment: I just read up on ffill(), which is the reverse of bfill(), so that takes care of that part. For some reason, though, the summing is not working. I end up with two rows with everything the same except the CONFIRMED numbers.

Comment: I ended up putting it in a new dataframe to get the summing to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I wasn't available yesterday. Yes, there may have been some changes, without the data (but you now provided it) it was a little harder. Glad it helped though!